# E2E_CLI Error when run Fabric example e2e_cli script.sh (Error: can't read the block: &{SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE}

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

While trying to setup the E2E_CLi network, we are getting the below error while trying to check whether the Order service is Up and running. Has anyone else faced this issue? In case anyone has any tips to resolve this issue, can you please share the same.

I am running HLF on Ubuntu 16.04, Docker version 17.12.0-ce, build c97c6d6, Hyperledger GIT * release-1.3.

Please let me know in case you are looking for any other input, as I am trying to resolve the same for couple of days and am a beginner to HLF.

=============
2018-11-28 10:00:24.740 UTC [cli/common] readBlock -> INFO 043 Got status: &{SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE}
Error: can't read the block: &{SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE}
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! Ordering Service is not available, Please try again ... !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
================== ERROR !!! FAILED to execute End-2-End Scenario ==================

Comment: We've actually removed e2e_cli in the master branch.  The preferred starting point is https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/tree/release-1.3/first-network